# How to handle paging of child collections in REST

Tags: json, rest, collections, paging, children

I have an entity where there are several child collections. Some of these collections can in some cases contain many items (> 100). In most cases however, there are about 1-10, which is fine.

When I display my main entity I want to display these child collection with paging, if there are more than 10 records.

As I don't want to wrap my JSON response in an envelope I'm using a Content-Range header (e.g. Content-Range: entities 11-20/400) that I add to the response when I'm getting collections in general. In this case I'm getting one single entity with several collections attached to it.

(example entity response to a "GET entities/123?AnotherChildrenCollection.PageSize=15&Children.PageSize=10&AnotherChidrenCollection.PageIndex=1"

"entities"

{ 
  ID: 123, 
  Children: [ { ChildID: 1 }, ... ]  // e.g. an actual total count of 122
  AnotherChildrenCollection: [ { ChildID: 1 }, ... ]  // e.g. an actual total count of 130
}

The only idea how so far is to extend the Content-Range header with all child collections coma separated and parse that.

e.g. like this:

Content-Range: entities.Children 0-9/122, entities.AnotherChildrenCollection 15-29/130

Is there are better or more standard way of handling this, as this feels a bit like a "hack"

Comment: Could you just get the children when they're needed instead of getting the main entity every time?

Comment: I want to display them at the same time as the main entity and I want to avoid making a request to the server for each child collection. This is to have a better user experience, compared to if the user would have to expand each collection from the UI before being able to see what data that is there.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.16) does not allow for using content-range in this fashion. It explicitly calls for a byte-range only. Consider using [link headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) instead.

For instance,

```
Link: <"http://foo/bar">"; rel=next
```

Add multiple link headers, where each `rel=` value indicates the relationship. In your case, use "first", "previous", "next", "last". Note that if you do this, you will lose the total number of records. This is one reason why people use envelopes.

EDIT: It appears my reading of the HTTP spec is not accurate. What the relevant section is saying is that clients are not *required* to respect any other range type. They still may, if they choose to. I'd still consider using link headers.

Comment: When using envelopes I would have to wrap each collection in an envelope as well and not have them directly attached to the main entity, that doesnt look like a good solution either, or do you include child collection total counts etc in the main envelope?